# TypeScript build error in Jenkins but not locally

Tags: typescript, jenkins

Hello i have an issue with one of my Jenkins pipelines when trying to build a TypeScript application.

The pipeline checkouts the TypeScript project and runs:

```
yarn install
yarn build
```

However during the build i errors and the pipeline fails with the error:

```
│       TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

I tried to recreate this error on an AWS EC2 instance which uses the same AMI image as my Jenkins EC2. I made sure to use the same version of node (v12.22.3) that my Jenkins service is using. However after running yarn install + build, I don't get this error. And the build succeeds.

I can see the error in Jenkins logs is referring to an 'error' variable:

```
      } catch (error) {
        expect(error.name).toEqual('Error');
      }
```

And after googling this error it seems like the solution could be to update the code to include a type on the error object (due to a TypeScript update), however this isn't my code, i'm not a typescript dev, and i know the code builds on my VM using the same version as node.js. So surely i can get it to work on Jenkins?

Does any one have any tips to help debug this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm betting you have different versions of Typescript installed. You may have different versions of typescript installed.

In Typescript 3.5.1 a caught error was of type `any`. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.5.1#code/C4JwngBA3gsAUBRECGAKAlPAvhAxs4XAC1QFMQR1p4k8B7AOwGc6AbUgOlboHMyLMCJAHphEciAgBLJhGBgADqRQMw2IA)

In Typescript 4.6.2 a caught error was of type `unknown`. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4JwngBA3gsAUBRECGAKAlPAvhAxs4XAC1QFMQR1p4k8B7AOwGc6AbUgOlboHMyLMCJAHphtcRAB6AfmxA)

Looks like was in Typescipt 4.4 ([see this release note](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#defaulting-to-the-unknown-type-in-catch-variables---useunknownincatchvariables)).

Somewhere in between those two versions the type was changed. And it looks like your CI server is running a more recent version than your local environment is.

And if your machine and your CI server are depending on a globally installed typescript the versions could be very different. I would recommend you update your local typescript to match what you have on CI.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I added a line to log the tsc version and saw it was using the wrong version due to a different package.json being used from another project.